# Get echo/noecho state in curses in python

Tags: python, curses

I can set the echo state in curses with `echo()` and `noecho()`, but how can I see what state I'm currently in? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
# get current echo state
if screen.echo_is_on():
    my_echo_state=False   # echo is currently off
    curses.echo()         # turn echo on
else:
    my_echo_state=True    # echo is already on

# get input from user
input_str = screen.getstr(r, c) 

# return echo to previous state
if my_echo_state==False:
    curses.noecho()
```

I'm looking for something to accomplish `screen.echo_is_on()`.

Comment: Don't compare with `False` or `True` - just do `if not screen.get_current_echo_state()`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you are right. fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *getter* function for `echo` in the Python [curses binding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

- Python has methods that correspond to the curses C functions.
- The state of `echo` (and some other functions) in the C binding are stored in the `SCREEN` struct, which traditionally is opaque.
- other state information is stored in `WINDOW` which was not opaque.

There are *extensions* to the original curses interface.  NetBSD introduced the notion of *opaque* structures for `WINDOW`, etc.  Later, ncurses adopted that as an option to help hide/control state information for threaded applications.  To do this, ncurses added functions for accessing data from `WINDOW` (see [curs_opaque(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_opaque.3x.html)).

However, there are no new functions for accessing the contents of `SCREEN`.  The enable/disable functions for those are described in [curs_inopts(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html).

If you need a *getter*, you could write one yourself, e.g., as a class which hides the actual calls to `echo` and `noecho`.

Comment: _There's no getter function for echo in the Python curses binding_ Not the easy answer I wanted, but a thorough response nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but curses does have `curses.wrapper` which sets "cbreak mode, turns off echo, enables the terminal keypad, and initializes colors if the terminal has color support" then runs your function. When your function returns it restores "cooked mode, turns on echo, and disables the terminal keypad". It also properly restores the terminal when your program throws an exception. A thorougly handy feature.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

Comment: I suppose it's nice that it tries to do that, but `curses.endwin` does the actual work in the ncurses `endwin` function.  That's where the terminal I/O is modified -- not in the Python wrapper.  Actually, having the curses wrapper change the in-screen settings like that is not necessarily a good thing, since curses applications can (and do) switch in and out of screen mode.